# Is it possible to replace just the inside handle of a screen door?

Tags: doors, replacement

[image: Bent handle]

I found the inside handle like this today. My housemate and my wife have professed ignorance on how it got that way. As a result of the handle getting cranked about 20 degrees from horizontal, the latch no long allows the door to close all of the way. Would I just be replacing the inside assembly? Inner and outer handle? The entire door?

Comment: are you sure that it is broken?

Comment: It still moves back and forth, but only with a bit of effort.

Comment: that is not an answer to my question

Comment: @jsotola: I suppose the answer then, is, no. All I know is that the handle is bent and that it no longer moves as freely as it used to. That suggests "broken" to me, but I'm far from an expert.

Comment: remove the handle from the door ... it is held on by two screws ... you may be able to see inside the assembly ... maybe something popped out of position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to places like Home Depot , Lowes, Ace hardware, or any large hardware type store, show them the part a they should have what you need.